# Wikiquote RSS/Feed for xml parsing

Tags: xml, rss, wikipedia-api, wikimedia

Is there a way to pull quotes from wikiquote via feed/rss? The usage would be for a quote generator. I've checked the source and the link to the feed does not work. It's hard to search for because I keep getting search results defining RSS and Feed through wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser does this trick! http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/